# How to calculate this limit with L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^2e^{1/x}$, but I have no idea how this limit is supposed to calculated.

EDIT: After writing it as $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{-2}}$, use L'Hôpital's Rule twice:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(e^{\frac{1}{x}})'}{(x^{-2})'} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{xe^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(xe^{\frac{1}{x}})'}{(2)'} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}}{0}$

So, as my math level (low) tell me a thing $e^{\frac{1}{x}} > \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x}} - \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} > 0$

Does this mean answer is $\inf$? Or I just failed?

Comment: Show us some effort. We're not a homework-doing service, although we are here to help. But first we need to know where you got stuck.

Comment: To apply l'hopital write as $e^{\frac{1}{x}}/x^{-2}$ then do l'hopital twice.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus he is supposed to solve the exercise without l'Hôpital.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia No, this task supposed to be solved with l'Hôpital.

Comment: It is true that the limit does not exist.  I am not sure that that is what your work shows.

Comment: If you are going to solve this using L'Hopitals rule you need to find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = xe^{\frac 1x}$ might i suggest $g(x) = e^{-\frac 1x}.$  Also, think about what happens approaching 0 from the left and from the right.

Comment: @AlexD I see. If that is the case, I have provided a solution to your exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit, as it has been proposed, does not exist.

However both side limits exist.

Indeed, if we make the change of variable $y = 1/x$ and approach $0$ from the right, it results that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0;x\in(0,\infty)}x^{2}e^{1/x} = \lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{e^{y}}{y^{2}} = +\infty
\end{align*}

On the other hand, if we make the same change of variable, but approach $0$ from the left, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0;x\in(-\infty,0)}x^{2}e^{1/x} = \lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{e^{y}}{y^{2}} = 0
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !